# Manual command to failback a keepalived cluster

Tags: high-availability, keep-alive, failover

I'm running a test keepalived cluster with two nodes, using the `nopreempt` option. This allows me to prevent automatic failback to the Primary node after a crash. That configuration is working fine.

Therefore, I'm looking for an elegant way to trigger a manual failback once I ensured that the Primary node is healthy.

I already have found two solutions, but I don't consider them as elegant :

- Stop the `keepalived` service on the Secondary Node

I was hoping to find a way to "move" the cluster ressources manually without having to stop the `keepalived` service.

- Configure a dummy interface as explained [here](https://www.virtualtothecore.com/en/manual-failover-of-keepalived/):

I believe this option is good for tests, but not for production.

Do you know a better way to trigger a failover on a keepalived cluster ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

How about increasing it's priority to a level you're certain it's the highest of the cluster. Followed by a `service keepalived reload`?